# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable?

Tags: python

I was implementing the dynamic programming algorithm and I got this error. This is my code:

```
def shoot(aliens):
    s=[0]*10
    s[0]=0
    s[1]=0
    for j in xrange(2,len(aliens)):
        for i in xrange(0,j):
           s[j]=max(s[i] + min(aliens[j],fib(j-i))) <---Error here
    print s[len(aliens)-1]
    return s[len(aliens)-1]

def fib(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

aliens=[1,10,10,1]
print shoot(aliens)
```

it says that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "module1.py", line 30, in <module>
print shoot(aliens)
File "module1.py", line 19, in shoot
s[j]=max(s[i] + min(aliens[j],fib(j-i)))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Please help me

UPDATE:
oh, I get it.
I mean

```
s[j]=max(s[i] + min(aliens[j],fib(j-i)))
```

But im wrong.
so, I edited it like that, but I do not know how to use max() to take out the largest in an array.

```
    b=0
    for j in xrange(2,len(aliens)):
        for i in xrange(0,j):
           a[b]=(s[i] + min(aliens[j],fib(j-i)))
           b+=1
        s[j]=Largest(a[b]);   <--How can I do that with Max() function
```

Comment: Did you try `max(a)`?

Comment: This error arises also with `min(value, *set())` where the second argument is intended to usually be nonempty, but can occasionally be empty. A simple workaround is `min(value, value, *set())`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`max` and `min` functions require several arguments or a range of elements. Your call to `min()` has two arguments (ok), but your call to `max()` has only one. Not sure what you want to maximize here...

Answer (score 2):

You are doing something like following:

```
>>> max(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Did you want to do this?

```
s[j] = max(s[i], min(aliens[j],fib(j-i)))
```

or

```
s[j] = max(s[j], s[i] + min(aliens[j],fib(j-i)))
```

Answer (score 1):

`max` needs an iterable argument.

> max(...) 
>           max(iterable[, key=func]) -> value
>           max(a, b, c, ...[, key=func]) -> value
>           With a single iterable argument, return its largest item.
>           With two or more arguments, return the largest argument.

But what you passed to it by `s[i] + min(aliens[j],fib(j-i))` is an `int`. What you want may be `s[j]=max(s[i], min(aliens[j],fib(j-i)))`

Answer (score 1):

It means you cannot iterate over a single `int` object.

`max()` and `min()` want either a number of values of whose they return the largest resp. the smallest, or they want an objkect which can be iterated over.

Your `max()` call is executed with one single argument which, then, should be iterable, but isn't.

Answer (score 1):

It should be, `s[j] = max(s[i], min(aliens[j], fib(j-i)))`, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max

```
max(iterable[, key])
max(arg1, arg2, *args[, key])
```

didn't you mean:

```
s[j] = max(s[i], min(aliens[j],fib(j-i)))
```