# int' object is not iterable - trying to learn python

Tags: python, list, object, int, iterable

I'm trying to learn python and I made this code to pratice. The objective is to read a list and if number is odd, another list receive it:

```
def purify(numlist):
    imp = [] #list that receive the odd numbers
    for n in range(0,len(numlist[n])): #travel a list of numbers inputted by user 
        if n % 2 != 0: #verify if number is pair or odd
            imp = numlist[n] #assigns odd numbers to the new list
    return imp #return list of odd numbers
```

But I'm receiving an error:

```
'int' object is not iterable
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you pass in as `numlist`? And can you show an example input, and what you would like the output to be?

Comment: Your code will actually fail with a `UnboundLocalError` for `n`, because you cannot yet use `n` when doing `len(numlist[n])`.

Comment: Can you give us the **full traceback** of your error, as well as a sample `numlist` value, please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718895/typeerror-int-object-is-not-iterable)

Comment: @ZeissIkon: where do you see a `min()` or `max()` call here? That's not a suitable dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I keep your way of writing this function.

```
def purify(numlist):
    imp = [] 
    # numlist is iterable. range builtin would list all integers between 0 and the value.
    for n in numlist:  
         # As pointed out in comments, the n variable will receive each number of the list iteratively. It is NOT the length of the list. 
        if n % 2 != 0: 
            # append method will add the element to the list. if you use assignemnt (=),
            # your variable imp will become an integer.
            imp.append(n)  
    return imp
```

The more practical way to do is

```
imp = filter(lambda n: n % 2 != 0, numlist)  # using a python built-in
```

or

```
imp = [n for n in numlist if n % 2 != 0]  # using list comprehension
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made like this:

```
def purify(numlist):
    imp = []
    for n in range(0,len(numlist)):
        if numlist[n] % 2 == 0:
            imp.append(numlist[n])
    return imp
```

It's working! thank you guys!